# rails console gives method_missing, undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-console

I am following a Rails tutorial and have to run rails console. I never had a issue with it before but now it doesn't run.

Here's the error.

```
    /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `generators' for
#<Rails::Railtie::Configuration:0x007ffc41d4a9a0> (NoMethodError)
        from /Users/lexi87/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.0.beta.18/lib/rspec-rails.rb:4:in `<class:Railtie>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your rspec gem is the same version as listed here: ["rails generate rspec:install" seems to be failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236132/rails-generate-rspecinstall-seems-to-be-failing)

Maybe that will help.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot I degraded my rpec version